# Model validation not working in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a validation in one of my models: (The sku_code validation.)

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases

  validates :name, format: {with: /\A[A-Za-z0-9\S\s]+\z/, message: "Vendor name is invalid."}
  validates :sku_code, format: {with: /\A[A-Z]{3}\z/, message: "must follow format ABC"}

end
```

Controller:

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @vendors = Vendor.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

  def new
    @vendor = Vendor.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

  def create
    @vendor = Vendor.new(vendor_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vendor.save
        format.html { redirect_to @vendor, notice: 'Vendor successfully created.' }
        format.js   {}
        format.json { render json: @vendor, status: :created, location: @vendor }
      else
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @vendor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vendor.update(vendor_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @vendor, notice: 'Vendor successfully updated.' }
        format.js   {}
        format.json { render json: @vendor, status: :updated, location: @vendor }
      else
        format.html { render 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @vendor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])
    @vendor.destroy
    #flash.notice="Vendor '#{@vendor.name}' was deleted."
    redirect_to action: "index"
  end

  def show
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

  private
    def vendor_params
      params.require(:vendor).permit(:name, :sku_code, :contact, :phone, :email, :address_line1, :address_line2, :address_city, :address_state, :address_zip, :address_country, :lead_time)
    end
end
```

What I expected with this regex was that it would allow for a three capital letter string to be entered into my form but prevent anything else.

Currently it is rejecting the three capital letter string.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure it rejects a three letter string like 'ABC'? I don't see anything wrong with the regex.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. I keep trying it and it rejects it.

Comment: Have you got any other validation on `sku_code`?

Comment: No other validations for sku_code.

Comment: A new record won't save so there wouldn't be an object to call it on. Unless I'm wrong.

Comment: My bad. I should've been clear. `obj = YourClassName.new(sku_code: 'AAA'); obj.save; obj.errors.full_messages`

Comment: The regex is fine: http://rubular.com/r/JmvpYnl3VW, something else must be wrong. Show more code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the whole model.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full model code.

Comment: @ArunKumar I got this: `obj = Vendor.new(sku_code: "AAA", name: "Test Name"); obj.save; obj.errors.full_messages
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: @NeyLive  Did you run the code in a rails console?

Comment: Arun Kumar I will try it again in console later.

Comment: @ArunKumar It works in rails console but does not work in the app. Is it possible that in rails console the validation is bypassed?

Comment: @NeyLive Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @ArunKumar Just added my controller code.

Comment: @NeyLive I thought you weren't permitting `sku_code` in the strong parameters. What error do you get when you try to save from the app?

Comment: @ArunKumar Oh, I've made that mistake quite a few times before haha! It was the first thing I made sure to check. I'm just getting my validation error message: `Sku code must follow format ABC`

Comment: @NeyLive I see. Is your code publicly available(on github, bitbucket)? I am curious to figure out the reason for the failure.

Comment: @ArunKumar Unfortunately, the code isn't publicly available. I'll try and figure it out tomorrow. Too exhausted to think right now.

Comment: @NeyLive Can you post your form code?